# Can we use CASE statement outside select or update query. CASE statement on Input Parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I want to use CASE statement something like below code or any other suggestion to implement said scenario.

I will be using this in some SP `where @UpdateStatus` I will be getting as input parameter.

Please suggest.

```
DECLARE @UpdateStatus nvarchar(20)
SET @UpdateStatus='P'
 CASE 
    WHEN @UpdateStatus='P' THEN
     BEGIN
        BEGIN TRAN
            Print 'A' --Update some table
        COMMIT
     END
    WHEN @UpdateStatus='F' THEN 
     BEGIN
        BEGIN TRAN
            Print 'B' --Update some table
        COMMIT
     END
 END
```

Comment: in this case, you have to use IF Else Statement

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [IF Else Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx) to handle different value

```
DECLARE @UpdateStatus nvarchar(20)
SET @UpdateStatus='P'
 IF @UpdateStatus='P'
     BEGIN
        BEGIN TRAN
            Print 'A' --Update some table
        COMMIT
     END
 ELSE IF @UpdateStatus='F'
     BEGIN
        BEGIN TRAN
            Print 'B' --Update some table
        COMMIT
     END
```

Comment: just replace CASE with IF in what OP has, so he can easily figure out, what needs to be changed, although END are optional.

Comment: I understand answering with as near to OP code as possible, but with the extra end ssms gives ... "Incorrect syntax near 'END'." instead of running the query.